# Rendering <img> tag in table

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, html

I am attempting to render noImageURL when icon.image is null. For some reason, noImageURL is always rendered. It's not respecting the  javascript if statement

```
  <td>
       <apex:image value="{!icon.image}" styleClass="img-responsive" alt="{!icon.image}" height="150" width="150" rendered="{!IF(icon.image != null && icon.image != '' && icon.image != 'null', true, false)}" />
       <img src="{!noImageURL}" styleClass="img-responsive" alt ="noImage" height="150" width="150" rendered="{!IF(icon.image == null, true, false)}"/>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah don't try to use `rendered` into a `img` tag, it's only for apex.

Updated :

```
<td>
    <apex:image value="{!icon.image}" styleClass="img-responsive" alt="{!icon.image}" height="150" width="150" rendered="{!IF(icon.image != null && icon.image != '' && icon.image != 'null', true, false)}" />
    <apex:image value="{!noImageURL}" styleClass="img-responsive" alt ="noImage" height="150" width="150" rendered="{!IF(icon.image == null, true, false)}"/>
</td>
```

Comment: So how do I go about this?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: I actually switched to using a static resource. Thanks for your help mate. much appreciated.